# How to set the size of a font from a file in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I want for my GUI to make my font bigger, as I saw it is really simple to do that with a regular font, but I didn't find anything on custom fonts from files, my current code looks like this:

```java
InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/mycustomfont.ttf");
try {
    assert is != null;
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is); // I get the font here but I don't have any options to change it's size
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(42f);
```

See [`Font.deriveFont(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) for details. In fact, *always* refer to the documentation before asking questions. That's what it's for.

Comment: thanks, I was only using the java doc of IntelliJ for that and I was searching a method with "size" in it

Comment: To be fair, the documentation is confusing, long and contains many times the same method name with a different signature. And `font.deriveFont(42f)` is completely different than `font.deriveFont(42)`. Yes, RTFM, but it doesn't help much when TFM is kinda useless.